# VIM, recognize .pyp as a python file

Tags: python, vim, cinema-4d

I'm doing some plugin programming for cinema 4d in python and decided to man up and start using a *real* code editor, VIM. followed the instructions on this page:

http://sontek.net/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide

my question is what changes do i have to make to the .vimrc file to get vim to recognize cinema 4d python files, they have a .pyp suffix. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but i'm just starting out on vim and would sure appreciate a leg up here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `autocmd` to set the filetype when opening an existing or starting a new file.  I think this should do it:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.pyp set filetype=python
```

See `:help autocmd` for the full details of how this works.